# Has anyone compiled all the NTSB accident reports and broke down the percentages for cause of accident and fatalities?

Tags: safety, general-aviation, ntsb

I am not talking the typical breakdown such as Pilot/Mechanical/Other, but rather, more specific things such as, engine failure, Stall/Spin on approach, controlled flight into terrain... etc

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is [the Nall report](http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/Safety-and-Technique/Accident-Analysis/Joseph-T-Nall-Report) - I'm not sure if that's the level of granularity you're looking for though...

Comment: @raptortech97 I think you are looking for avherald.com but that doesn't include all reports for various reasons

Comment: @voretaq7 - This is great information about the conditions and type of flight, but I still don't see the cause on there anywhere.

Comment: Out of interest what do you want the information for?

Comment: I am an engineer/entrepreneur, and I'm hoping to create my own airplane company. I am doing initial research into the feasibility of making an electric (possibly VTOL) LSA which compensates for most pilot mistakes with an end goal of making a GA plane flight safer than a car ride.

Comment: @David It already is.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans - Unfortunately, this is not the case for GA aircraft, only commercial. The safest GA plane by record is the Diamond DA40 (with the popular C172 close behind). It has a fatality rate of 0.35/100,000 hours flown. For Driving, the statistic is around .588 fatalities per million hours driven. Even taking into account miles traveled, the safest plane was still at least 4x times the risk in a best case scenario.

Comment: @David - I suspect the hard part of designing an LSA which compensates for pilot mistakes won't be when the pilot tries to do the right thing and fails, it will be compensating for when the pilot tries to do the wrong thing, and succeeds.

Comment: @SteveV. - I agree. Most accidents are a series of thoughtless mistakes which is the true tragedy. Making GA safe from this is the first step to truly safe, near automated flight.

Comment: Have you seen https://aviation-safety.net/ ?

Comment: @AnthonyX - Yes, I have, but I don't believe they break it out by cause on a large scale basis but still a great site. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: 2 big causes are VFR flight into IMC, and running out of fuel.  Since you're suggesting VTOL, create a system that can auto-land when IMC is encountered (autodetect weather? pilot hits panic button) maybe allow the pilot to take control back when VMC is encountered again), and auto-land when there's still sufficient fuel/battery charge TO land (i.e. don't let the plane run out). And put it on floats in case the landing is over water.    I think you can only take so much danger out of flying before you take the utility out of flying tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a book called "The Killing Zone - How and Why Pilots Die" by Paul A. Craig which has a great deal of statistical work in it around aircraft accidents which may be useful to you. It's an alarming title which might make you think it's some sort of sky is falling mentality, but it's actually very sensible, statistics-based information about aviation accidents.